# How to group the GitHub workflow jobs in visualization?

Tags: github-actions

I'm using the reusable workflow, structure like root.yml, build.yml and package.yml. In 1st run, two jobs in build.yml were grouped, but in 2nd run, two jobs were splited without workflow code change. I like the first one, how to restore it back?
[image]
[image]